# Unable to send MMS using Android 2.3.4, but 2.2.2 is fine. Issue with MOBILE_MMS and MOBILE data active together?

Tags: android, mms

I have created an Android app that sends an MMS in response to receiving SMS. The application works well - on an LG Optimus ME running Android 2.2.2. However, the application fails to send the MMS when running on a Samsung Galaxy S 2 running Android 2.3.4. It fails at the point where the application is attempting to open an outputstream to the Mobile provider's MMS server via a proxy (as defined in the relevant APN). It just times out.

I have captured logs of the app running on the two devices, and the only significant difference is that, on the LG Optimus ME, when I enable MMS by calling `ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, "enableMMS")`, the MOBILE network service automatically disconnects. On the Samsung Galaxy S 2, the MOBILE network service remains connected. I do use `ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost()` to ensure that the APN proxy is contactable.

Here are the log messages. I'm sorry they're so long, but hopefully someone will be able to explain why the connection to the APN proxy fails on the Samsung, but succeeds on the LG. I'm guessing it's because the mobile data connection doesn't get disabled, as it does on the LG. The other interesting point is the the **reason** given for `CONNECTIVTY_CHANGE` on the LG is **apnSwitched**, and on the Samsung, it's **apnEnabled**.

Optimus LG ME (Android 2.2.2)

```
11-25 10:57:10.599: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Obtaining connectivity manager
11-25 10:57:10.599: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Registering receiver
**11-25 10:57:10.609: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Attempting to use MMS network feature**
11-25 10:57:10.619: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Now starting watchdog, which will wait for 60000 milliseconds
11-25 10:57:10.629: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$1(2786): Watchdog has started
11-25 10:57:10.629: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): onReceive(): Intent action is android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
11-25 10:57:10.629: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): No Conectivity Status: false, Reason :apnSwitched, FailOver :true, Current Network Info : NetworkInfo: type: **mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnSwitched**, extra: www.vodafone.net.nz, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, OtherNetwork Info :null
11-25 10:57:10.639: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): **Current network type is mobile**
11-25 10:57:10.639: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Connection status: **true**
11-25 10:57:10.759: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(2786): surfaceCreated()
11-25 10:57:10.759: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(2786): surfaceCreated() has finished
11-25 10:57:10.759: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$1(2786): CameraPreviewCallback: Surface created
11-25 10:57:10.769: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(2786): Surface changed: We ignore this
11-25 10:57:10.769: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$1(2786): CameraPreviewCallback: Surface change completed
11-25 10:57:11.299: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): onReceive(): Intent action is android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
11-25 10:57:11.299: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): No Conectivity Status: true, Reason :apnSwitched, FailOver :false, Current Network Info : **NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: apnSwitched**, extra: www.vodafone.net.nz, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: false, OtherNetwork Info :null
11-25 10:57:11.309: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Current network type is **mobile**
11-25 10:57:11.309: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Connection status: **false**
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): onReceive(): Intent action is android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): No Conectivity Status: false, Reason :apnSwitched, FailOver :false, Current Network Info : **NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[HSDPA], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnSwitched**, extra: live.vodafone.com, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, OtherNetwork Info :null
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Current network type is **mobile_mms**
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Connection status: **true**
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): MMS connectivity established
11-25 10:57:16.499: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(2786): Watchdog is alive, so interrupting
11-25 10:57:16.519: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager$1(2786): Watchdog interrupted. Assuming we are now connected
11-25 10:57:16.539: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Checking MMS connectivity state
11-25 10:57:16.539: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): We are now connected. Now setting network preference to TYPE_MOBILE_MMS
11-25 10:57:16.549: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.MmsConnectivityManager(2786): Firing mmsConnectivityEnabled
11-25 10:57:16.549: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(2786): MMS connectivity established. Taking picture ...
11-25 10:57:16.549: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(2786): Debug: check connectivity to Vodafone NZ MMS proxy. Address is -1407310333
11-25 10:57:16.549: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(2786): MMS: true
11-25 10:57:16.549: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker(2786): Taking picture ...
11-25 10:57:17.002: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$4(2786): Shutter callback
11-25 10:57:17.299: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$5(2786): Raw picture callback.
11-25 10:57:17.299: W/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$5(2786): Picture data is null.
11-25 10:57:17.329: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$6(2786): Jpeg picture taken. 2424 bytes
11-25 10:57:17.339: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$6(2786): Sending PXT to +6421XXXXXX
11-25 10:57:17.339: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Sending JPEG via MMS to +6421XXXXXX
11-25 10:57:17.339: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Adding content to message
11-25 10:57:17.349: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Message encoded
11-25 10:57:17.359: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Getting list of APNs
11-25 10:57:17.369: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Using APN: MMS Center URL: http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend, MMS Port: 8080, MMS Proxy: 172.030.038.003
11-25 10:57:17.369: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): [MMSCenter]http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend, [MMSProxy]172.030.038.003, [MMSPort]8080
11-25 10:57:17.369: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Sending...
11-25 10:57:17.369: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): MMS URL is http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend
11-25 10:57:17.369: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Setting proxy to: 172.030.038.003:8080
11-25 10:57:17.379: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Proxy: HTTP//172.30.38.3:8080
11-25 10:57:17.379: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Creating decoder
11-25 10:57:17.379: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Decoding header
11-25 10:57:17.379: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Getting message
11-25 10:57:17.379: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Opening connection
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Connection opened. Using proxy: true. Setting doOutput
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Connection timeout is 0. Adding 60 seconds
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Connection timeout is now 60000
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Reading header
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): [X-NOKIA-MMSC-Charging]100
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Setting request properties
11-25 10:57:17.389: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Getting output stream
11-25 10:57:22.729: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): **Writing data to output stream. 2531 bytes**
11-25 10:57:22.729: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Finished writing to output stream. About to close it ...
11-25 10:57:22.729: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Need to close output stream
11-25 10:57:22.729: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Now waiting for response. Getting response code
11-25 10:57:24.849: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Reading response
11-25 10:57:25.039: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Getting response headers
11-25 10:57:25.039: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Closing output stream
11-25 10:57:25.039: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Closing input stream
11-25 10:57:25.049: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Closing connection
11-25 10:57:25.049: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(2786): Closing connection and finishing
11-25 10:57:25.049: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): Message sent to http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend
11-25 10:57:25.059: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): **Response code: 200 OK**
11-25 10:57:25.059: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): DATE: Thu, 24 Nov 2011 21:57:28 GMT
11-25 10:57:25.059: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): CONTENT-TYPE: application/vnd.wap.mms-message
11-25 10:57:25.059: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): CONTENT-LENGTH: 33
11-25 10:57:25.069: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): ACCEPT-RANGES: bytes
11-25 10:57:25.069: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): SERVER: XMS (724Solutions HTA XMA_40_M0_B093 20090820.094517)
11-25 10:57:25.069: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(2786): **MMS sent to +6421XXXXXX successfully**
```

Samsung Galaxy S 2 (Android 2.3.4)

```
11-25 10:59:09.070: 11-25 10:59:09.070: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Obtaining connectivity manager
11-25 10:59:09.070: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Registering receiver
11-25 10:59:09.070: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Attempting to use MMS network feature
11-25 10:59:09.075: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Now starting watchdog, which will wait for 60000 milliseconds
11-25 10:59:09.080: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): onReceive(): Intent action is android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
11-25 10:59:09.085: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): No Conectivity Status: false, Reason :apnEnabled, FailOver :false, Current Network Info : **NetworkInfo: type: mobile[UMTS], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnEnabled**, extra: www.vodafone.net.nz[disabled], roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, OtherNetwork Info :null
11-25 10:59:09.085: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): Current network type is **mobile**
11-25 10:59:09.085: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): Connection status: **true**
11-25 10:59:09.090: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$1(4986): Watchdog has started
11-25 10:59:09.130: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(4986): surfaceCreated()
11-25 10:59:09.155: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(4986): surfaceCreated() has finished
11-25 10:59:09.155: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$1(4986): CameraPreviewCallback: Surface created
11-25 10:59:09.160: I/ck.android.spycam.CameraPreview(4986): Surface changed: We ignore this
11-25 10:59:09.160: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$1(4986): CameraPreviewCallback: Surface change completed
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): onReceive(): Intent action is android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): No Conectivity Status: false, Reason :apnEnabled, FailOver :false, Current Network Info : **NetworkInfo: type: mobile_mms[HSDPA], state: CONNECTED/CONNECTED, reason: apnEnabled**, extra: live.vodafone.com, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, OtherNetwork Info :null
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): Current network type is **mobile_mms**
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): Connection status: **true**
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): MMS connectivity established
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$MyConnectivityReceiver(4986): Watchdog is alive, so interrupting
11-25 10:59:12.975: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager$1(4986): Watchdog interrupted. Assuming we are now connected
11-25 10:59:12.980: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Checking MMS connectivity state
11-25 10:59:12.980: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): We are now connected. **Now setting network preference to TYPE_MOBILE_MMS**
11-25 10:59:12.980: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Firing mmsConnectivityEnabled
11-25 10:59:12.980: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(4986): MMS connectivity established. Taking picture ...
11-25 10:59:12.980: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(4986): **Debug: check connectivity to Vodafone NZ MMS proxy. Address is -1407310333**
11-25 10:59:12.985: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(4986): MMS: true
11-25 10:59:12.985: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker(4986): Taking picture ...
11-25 10:59:14.030: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$4(4986): Shutter callback
11-25 10:59:14.435: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$5(4986): Raw picture callback.
11-25 10:59:14.525: W/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$5(4986): Picture data is null.
11-25 10:59:14.615: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$6(4986): Jpeg picture taken. 128909 bytes
11-25 10:59:14.615: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$6(4986): Sending PXT to +6421XXXXXXX
11-25 10:59:14.615: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): Sending JPEG via MMS to +6421XXXXXXX
11-25 10:59:14.620: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): Adding content to message
11-25 10:59:14.625: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): Message encoded
11-25 10:59:14.735: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): Getting list of APNs
11-25 10:59:14.765: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): Using APN: MMS Center URL: http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend, MMS Port: 8080, MMS Proxy: 172.030.038.003
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.MsgUtil(4986): [MMSCenter]http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend, [MMSProxy]172.030.038.003, [MMSPort]8080
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Sending...
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): MMS URL is http://pxt.vodafone.net.nz/pxtsend
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Setting proxy to: 172.030.038.003:8080
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Proxy: HTTP//172.30.38.3:8080
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Creating decoder
11-25 10:59:14.770: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Decoding header
11-25 10:59:14.775: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Getting message
11-25 10:59:14.775: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Opening connection
11-25 10:59:14.775: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Connection opened. Using proxy: true. Setting doOutput
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Connection timeout is 0. Adding 60 seconds
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Connection timeout is now 60000
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Reading header
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): [X-NOKIA-MMSC-Charging]100
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Setting request properties
11-25 10:59:14.780: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Getting output stream
11-25 10:59:52.245: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSender(4986): Closing connection
**11-25 10:59:52.250: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker(4986): Failure: ck.android.util.msg.mms.nokia.MMSenderException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out**
11-25 10:59:52.425: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Now disabling MMS connectivity
11-25 10:59:52.445: I/ck.android.util.msg.mms.deprecated.MmsConnectivityManager(4986): Firing mmsConnectivityDisabled
11-25 10:59:52.445: I/ck.android.spycam.act.PictureTaker$2(4986): MMS connectivity finished normally`
```

---

Constructor of MmsConnectivityManager, which is where we enable the MMS network feature

```
public MmsConnectivityManager(final Context context, final long timeout, MmsConnectivityCallback callback) throws MmsConnectivityException {
    if(callback == null) {
        throw new MmsConnectivityException("An MmsConnectivityCallback is required") ;
    }
    this.callback = callback ;
    Util.logI("Obtaining connectivity manager") ;
    cManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) ;

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    Util.logI("Registering receiver") ;
    context.registerReceiver(myConnectivityReceiver, filter) ;
    Util.logI("Attempting to use MMS network feature") ;
    if(cManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE, PhoneEx.FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS) == -1) {
        Util.logI("Cound not use MMS network feature") ;
        context.unregisterReceiver(myConnectivityReceiver) ;
        throw new MmsConnectivityException("Cound not use MMS network feature") ;
    }

    Util.logI("Now starting watchdog, which will wait for " + timeout + " milliseconds") ;

    // now we wait for timeout milliseconds. If the service doesn't come up
    // by then, we abort

    watchdogThread = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            Util.logI("Watchdog has started") ;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeout) ;
                Util.logI("Watchdog timeout has expired. No interruption detected") ;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Util.logI("Watchdog interrupted. Assuming we are now connected") ;
                connected = true ;
            }
            context.unregisterReceiver(myConnectivityReceiver) ;
            checkConnectivityState(context) ;
        }
    } ;
    watchdogThread.start() ;
}
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: please add full source code